# SQL Error: ORA-01841

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the following error when I run code in SQL Developer:

> SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"

I get this error when I try to create a table. Funnily when I just do the embedded select without the `create table` the code runs fine.

the sentence is:

```
 CREATE TABLE TEMP2 AS 
   select  LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(RDF.maxfiledate || '/01','yyyy/mm/dd')) as EXPOS
   from FOR_FRONTING3 FRO 
   left join RDF_TEMP RDF on FRO.POLICYNO = RDF.POLICYNO and FRO.LASTRENW = RDF.LASTRENW;
```

Any ideas why simply wrapping the select in a `create table` causes this error?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please *edit the question* and add your (formatted) code. What data type is  `RDF.maxfiledate`? If it's a date then you're implicitly converting that to a string before trying to add a day number, and should be supplying a format (or using a different approach); if it's a string then what values does the column contain?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I see now how it should have been posted. MAXFILEDATE is of datatype NUMBER.

Comment: What kind of number? Just a four-digit year? It's helpful to include table structures and sample data in the question too.

Comment: MAXFILEDATE is a six digit number showing year and month. Example: 201609

Comment: Is it always 6 digits? Are there any null values? I can see why it would fail with nulls (or maybe negative values), but not with that value (though you're relying on Oracle's flexibility in interpreting values); and if it fails on `create` it should also fail with the plain `select` - unless you're only retrieving a subset of rows (e.g. the first 50 via SQL Developer's Run Query option).

Comment: Yes it is always 6 digits. There are no nulls.

Comment: Since you are left-joining, there are presumably FRO rows with no matching  RDF row (otherwise why not use an inner join?); in that case `RDF.maxfiledate` will evaluate to null.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Alex. That's the solution - It evaluates to null when i do the left join. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, believe the error.  You have bad data.

In all likelihood, you are looking at the results from running the query and not seeing it -- because you are only looking at the first few results.  The `create table` is run over all the rows before it returns, so it will find the offending row.

The cause would be this line:

```
            then (LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(RDF.maxfiledate || '/01','yyyy/mm/dd')) - RDF.LASTRENW)/RDF.POL_DAYS_ERND
```

You should be able to find the offending line with something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM RDF_TEMP RDF
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(RDF.maxfiledate, '^[0-9]{4}/')
```

If the first four characters are digits, then Oracle shouldn't have a conversion problem with the *year*.

Comment: Every record fails the test you show above. Does this mean that maxfiledate is not a number somehow?

Comment: @amsbam1 - that pattern is based on the assumption that `maxfiledate` is a string with value like `'2016/09'`; it's checking all the values match that first part, essentially as starting with `YYYY/`. As you're since said it's a number not a string this turns out not to be helpful. You could instead search for rows that are not six-digit numbers, but we've established that isn't the issue either *8-)

Comment: @amsbam1 . . . Then your `to_date()` pattern makes no sense.  A string of the form, say, "200601/01" shouldn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your number, e.g. 201609, to a date using the format mask YYYY/MM/DD. You also have a left outer join between `for_fronting3` and `rdf_temp`. For any row in `FRO` which does not have a matching row in `RDF` the `RDF.maxfiledate` will evaluate to null, so you would be doing the equivalent of:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(null || '/01','yyyy/mm/dd') as EXPOS FROM DUAL;

Error report -
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

You need to prevent null values being used, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2 AS 
   select  CASE WHEN RDF.maxfiledate IS NOT NULL THEN
     LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(RDF.maxfiledate || '/01','yyyy/mm/dd')) END as EXPOS
   from FOR_FRONTING3 FRO 
   left join RDF_TEMP RDF on FRO.POLICYNO = RDF.POLICYNO and FRO.LASTRENW = RDF.LASTRENW;
```

You are likely to end up with multiple null values, which probably isn't very helpful unless you're really using other columns in your create/query. If you don't want any nulls in `TEMP2` then use an inner join instead of an outer join - which will skip the rows without matches.